# When my program runs why does the output stop after the input, i.e why does my code not completely run

Tags: python

I have tried placing the for loop without an indent as well as placing the function at the top of the code

```
import random
num_roll_str = input('How many time you want to roll the dice? ')
num_roll = int(num_roll_str)

def roll_2_dice():
  dice1 =  random.randint(1, 6)
  dice2 =  random.randint(1, 6)
  return dice1, dice2

for i in range (1, num_roll):
  print('{0:>10}{1:>10}{2:>10}'.format(i, dice1, dice2))

roll_2_dice()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because **indentation matters** and `return ...` leaves the function you are in.

Remove the indentation of your for loop so it belongs to your *main code* and not *into* your function )where it never would be executed because *after* `return`).

Also change `for i in range (1, num_roll):` to `for i in range (1, num_roll+1):` - the upper limit of `range` is *exclusive* so `range(1,4)` will give you 1,2,3:

```
import random
num_roll_str = input('How many time you want to roll the dice? ')
num_roll = int(num_roll_str)

def roll_2_dice():
    dice1 =  random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2 =  random.randint(1, 6)
    return dice1, dice2              # return is THE END, noting happens after it

for i in range (1, num_roll+1):
    d1, d2 = roll_2_dice()     # call your function and print it
    print('{0:>10}{1:>10}{2:>10}'.format(i, d1, d2))
```

I fixed the indentation to 4 spaces, see [pep 008 guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

Doku:

- [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

---

Output for 5:

```
          1         5         5
          2         1         2
          3         3         2
          4         2         6
          5         6         4
```

Comment: Instead of temp variables `d1, d2 = roll_2_dice()`,  you can just call `print('{0:>10}{1:>10}{2:>10}'.format(i, *roll_2_dice()))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code:

- Indentation problem
- You defined `roll_2_dice` function but never used it in your program.
- If you wanna roll your dice `num_roll times` you need to use the range function as `range(1,num_roll+1)`.

```py
import random
num_roll_str = input('How many time you want to roll the dice? ')
num_roll = int(num_roll_str)

def roll_2_dice():
    dice1 =  random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2 =  random.randint(1, 6)
    return dice1, dice2

for i in range (1, num_roll+1):
    dice1,dice2 = roll_2_dice()
    print('{0:>10}{1:>10}{2:>10}'.format(i, dice1, dice2))
```